# Remove Unwanted Space from Print Function

Tags: python, printing, removing-whitespace

I need to make a program in Python 3 which outputs the numbers that are not repeted given a sequence of numbers, I have done this so far:

```
a = list(map(int,input().split()))

for i in a:
    if a.count(i) == 1: 
        print(i,end=" ")
```

The problem is, if you type the following sequence "4 3 5 2 5 1 3 5", the output will be "4 2 1 " instead of "4 2 1" ( Which was the expected result). My question is, Is there a way to make the "end" argument not to print an extra space at the end?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you better do not let the `print(..)` add the spaces, but work with `str.join` instead:

```
print(' '.join(str(i) for i in a if a.count(i) == 1))
```

The boldface part is a generator, it yields the `str(..)` of all the `i`s in `a` where `a.count(i) == 1`. We then *join* these strings together with the space `' '` as separator.

Here print will still add a new line, but we can use `end=''` to disable that:

```
print(' '.join(str(i) for i in a if a.count(i) == 1), end='')
```

Comment: I see what you did there ! I am still a rookie in Python, therefor I didn't really know about "Generators". I will try to learn more about those ! Thank You ! :-)